# pipe sed command to create multiple files

Tags: regex, shell, command-line, sed

I need to get X to Y in the file with multiple occurrences, each time it matches an occurrence it will save to a file.

Here is an example file (demo.txt):

```
\x00START how are you? END\x00
\x00START good thanks END\x00
sometimes random things\x00\x00 inbetween it (ignore this text)
\x00START thats nice END\x00
```

And now after running a command each file (/folder/demo1.txt, /folder/demo2.txt, etc) should have the contents between \x00START and END\x00 (\x00 is null) in addition to 'START' but not 'END'.

/folder/demo1.txt should say "START how are you? ", /folder/demo2.txt should say "START good thanks".

So basicly it should pipe "how are you?" and using 'echo' I can prepend the 'START'.

It's worth keeping in mind that I am dealing with a very large binary file.

I am currently using

```
sed -n -e '/\x00START/,/END\x00/ p' demo.txt > demo1.txt
```

but that's not working as expected (it's getting lines before the '\x00START' and doesn't stop at the first 'END\x00').

Comment: Just an FYI, I don't think `sed` generally plays nicely with binary files...

Comment: Ah, any idea what else I could use? I tried grep but that didn't work nicely with binary files too.

Comment: What kind of a file is this? Why does it have those null-characters in it? Anyway, use the `-b` option for binary mode (doesn't matter on *nix), and use `\x00` to match a null character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have *GNU* `awk`, try:

```
 awk -v RS='\0START|END\0' '
      length($0) {printf "START%s\n", $0 > ("folder/demo"++i".txt")}
      ' demo.txt
```

- `RS='\0START|END\0'` defines a regular expression acting as the *[input] Record Separator* which breaks the input file into records by strings (byte sequences) between `\0START` and `END\0` (`\0` represents `NUL` (null char.) here).

  - Using a multi-character, regex-based record separate is NOT POSIX-compliant; *GNU* `awk` supports it (as does `mawk` *in general*, but seemingly not with `NUL` chars.).
- Pattern `length($0)` ensures that the associated action (`{...}`) is only executed if the records is *nonempty*.
- `{printf "START%s\n", $0 > ("folder/demo"++i)}` outputs each nonempty record preceded by `"START"`, into file `folder/demo{n}.txt"`, where `{n}` represent a sequence number starting with `1`.

Comment: +1 for using `RS` for this, neat approach.. I've got to remember to use it.

Comment: Thanks, @Tiago; note that while multi-char., regex-based `RS` values normally work in _both_ GNU `awk` _and_ `mawk`, in this particular case `mawk` doesn't work - presumably due to the `NUL` chars.

Comment: Trying this now & will get back to you.

Comment: @user3786834: Hope it works; note that if you're on Ubuntu, you may have to invoke it as `gawk`, because `awk` is by default linked to `mawk`.

Comment: @user3786834: Create a test file as follows: `echo $'@START how\nare you? END@@START good thanks END@sometimes random things@@ inbetween it (ignore this text@START thats nice END@' | tr @ '\0' > demo.txt`.

Comment: Perfect, this answer works and it lets you use a custom script which is cool. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` for that:

```
grep -Po "START\s+\K.*?(?=END)" file
how are you? 
good thanks 
thats nice
```

Explanation:

1. `-P` To allow Perl regex
2. `-o` To extract only matched pattern
3. `-K` Positive lookbehind
4. `(?=something)` Positive lookahead

**EDIT:** To match `\00` as `START` and `END` may appear in between:

```
echo -e '\00START hi how are you END\00' | grep -aPo '\00START\K.*?(?=END\00)'
 hi how are you
```

**EDIT2:** The solution using grep would only match single line, for multi-line it's better use `perl` instead. The syntax will be very similar:

```
echo -e '\00START hi \n how\n are\n you END\00' | perl -ne 'BEGIN{undef $/ } /\A.*?\00START\K((.|\n)*?)(?=END)/gm; print $1' 
 hi 
 how
 are
 you
```

What's new here:

1. `undef $/` Undefine INPUT separator `$/` which defaults to '\n'
2. `(.|\n)*` Dot matches almost any character, but it does not match
   `\n` so  we need to add it here.
3. `/gm` Modifiers, `g` for global `m` for multi-line

Comment: Thanks for your help but I need to use hex too as 'START' and 'END' can appear in the middle of the content.

Comment: @user3786834 Edited my answer, please mind the switch `-a` for binary as text

Comment: Snazzy, it's working! Thank you Tiago. Note: it's \x00 not \00 to get grep to work with hex.

Comment: @user3786834 '\x00' and '\00' has the same effect for me.

Comment: I've encountered a problem with it, it works when the 'END' is on the same line as the content, but if the contents is multiple lines it wont work.

Comment: @user3786834 Addressed the multi-line issue with `perl`

Answer (score 0):

I would translate the nulls into newlines so that `grep` can find your wanted text on a clean line by itself:

```
tr '\000' '\n' < yourfile.bin | grep "^START"
```

from there you can take it into `sed` as before.